# Error: The autoloader expected class ... to be defined in file. inSymfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, psr-4

For the update to Symfony 4.0, I added "_default" and "AppBundle" to services.yml and verified the operation, but the following error occurred.
I have two bundles and want to achieve automatic wiring for each.
Is there anything wrong with it?
https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

ErrorCode

```
The autoloader expected class "App\Sp\AppBundle\AppBundle" to   
  be defined in file "/home/vagrant/Symfony2/vendor/composer/../../src/App/Sp/AppBundle/AppBundle.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

services.yml

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/App/Sp/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/App/Sp/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,AppBundle.php}'

    CommonBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/App/Sp/CommonBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/App/Sp/CommonBundle/{Entity,Repository}'
```

AppBundle.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Sp\AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AhiSpAdminBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Comment: Why is the file named `AppBundle.php`, but the class is named `AhiSpAdminBundle`? Doesn't the error message tell you that this is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Composer

The composer.json PSR-4 autoloader in Symfony Flex by default applies a namespace for `App` from the `/src` path. The `App` namespace will apply to all of the subdirectories and files within the `src/` directory.

*composer.json*

```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

### Symfony Naming Conventions

Symfony naming conventions also require the `*Bundle.php` file to reside in a namespace of the same name [[sic]](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name) and [[sic]](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles.html#creating-a-bundle). This is comprised of the vendor or category name (Sp) and the namespace (AhiSpAdminBundle) to make `SpAhiSpAdminBundle`.

```yaml
| Namespace Bundle       | Class Name     |
|------------------------|----------------|
| Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle | AcmeBlogBundle |
| Acme\BlogBundle        | AcmeBlogBundle |
```

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/AcmeBlogBundle.php
namespace App\Acme\BlogBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeBlogBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

### PSR-4 Autoloading

Since the namespace is `App\Sp\AhiSpAdminBundle`, the filename and directory needs to be changed to match the namespace and Symfony bundle class name conventions respectively to `src/Sp/AhiSpAdminBundle/SpAhiSpAdminBundle.php`.

Rename the file to match the class name for the PSR-4 autoloader.

```sh
mv src/Sp/AppBundle/AppBundle.php src/Sp/AppBundle/SpAhiSpAdminBundle.php
```

Rename directory to match the namespace for the PSR-4 autoloader.

```sh
mv src/Sp/AppBundle src/Sp/AhiSpAdminBundle
```

### Symfony Services

Fix the namespace and class name of your bundle to adhere to the [Symfony naming conventions](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name).

```
// src/Sp/AhiSpAdminBundle/SpAhiSpAdminBundle.php
namespace App\Sp\AhiSpAdminBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class SpAhiSpAdminBundle extends Bundle
{
  //...
}
```

Then update your services definitions to match the PSR-4 pathing that is compatible with Symfony.

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\Sp\AhiSpAdminBundle\:
        resource: '../src/Sp/AhiSpAdminBundle/*'
        exclude: '../src/Sp/AhiSpAdminBundle/{Entity,Repository,SpAhiSpAdminBundle.php}'

    App\Sp\CommonBundle\:
        resource: '../src/Sp/CommonBundle/*'
        exclude: '../src/Sp/CommonBundle/{Entity,Repository}'
```

### Cleaning Up

Generate the autoloader files.

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

Clear and Warmup the Syfmony Cache.

```sh
rm -rf var/cache/dev
bin/console --env=dev cache:warmup
```

---

If needed repeat the process for the `CommonBundle` namespace, class name, and filename of `src/Sp/CommonBundle/SpCommonBundle.php` or restructure following the naming conventions to achieve the desired end-results.

```
// src/Sp/CommonBundle/SpCommonBundle.php
namespace App\Sp\CommonBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class SpCommonBundle extends Bundle
{
  //...
}
```

---

> While the vendor/category name (Sp) is optional in the bundle class
> name, with non-descriptive names like `AdminBundle` and
> `CommonBundle`, it is best-practice to include the category in the
> bundle name, as to ensure there are no naming conflicts and to better
> differentiate between them when debugging and unit-testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit familiar with Symfony, but my experience was developing an existing project not creating a new one, but looking at the error: `... The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

I think that explains it then? The file name is `AppBundle.php` but the class name is `AhiSpAdminBundle`. PHP usually use the same name for both file and class name so I think you should rename the class name to `AppBundle` or just rename the file name, basically make sure they're using the same name. (I assume Symfony is looking a class named `AppBundle` in a `AppBundle.php` file according to this "convention")

Comment: This is correct, they should rename the class to `AppBundle`